# Get success or error message from batch file executed on remote system over VPN

Tags: batch-file

Prerequisites: I have VPN access to the system with read/write permission to folders.

Case 1: I am executing four different bat file from a single controller which will copy files from that remote system defined in the specific location.

Case 2: Now I want to trigger bat, located on the remote system from my machine.

I want to get back the success or error message from it, just to get confirmed about its status.

I have attached few of the files for case 1.

```bat
@echo "******************Tualatin-script.bat*************************" 
@echo "*******************************************" 
color B
@echo Author        :- Madhur Gupta              
@echo Creation Date :- 12 Mar 2018        
@echo Project       :- LAM Research Corp      

@echo Create Folder Structure     
@Echo Run this Batch file before every test          
@echo "*******************************************"       
@echo "********************************************" 

@echo off

copy "\\LDTCIPLM01\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\Fremont\LDTCIPLM01\" /-y
copy "\\LDTCIPLM02\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\Fremont\LDTCIPLM02\" /-y
copy "\\LDTCIPLM03\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\Fremont\LDTCIPLM03\" /-y
copy "\\LDTCIPLM04\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\Fremont\LDTCIPLM04\" /-y
copy "\\a205276\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\Fremont\a205276\" /-y
copy "\\a3000146\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\Fremont\a3000146\" /-y
Exit
```

```bat
@echo "*******************************************" 
@echo "*******************************************" 
color B
@echo Author        :- Madhur Gupta              
@echo Creation Date :- 12 Mar 2018        
@echo Project       :- LAM Research Corp      

@echo To Pull Data     
@Echo Run this Batch file To Get Test Data       
@echo "*******************************************"       
@echo "********************************************" 
title Main Controller

call /b Script\India-script.bat
@echo "*******************************************" 
@echo "*******************************************" 
call /b Script\Tualatin-script.bat

pause
```

```bat
@echo "************India-script.bat*******************************" 
@echo "*******************************************" 
color B
@echo Author        :- Madhur Gupta              
@echo Creation Date :- 12 Mar 2018        
@echo Project       :- LAM Research Corp      

@echo Create Folder Structure     
@Echo Run this Batch file before every test          
@echo "*******************************************"       
@echo "********************************************" 

@echo off

copy "\\INDIPLMTEST01\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\India\INDIPLMTEST01\" /-y
copy "\\INDIPLMTEST02\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\India\INDIPLMTEST02\" /-y
copy "\\INDIPLMTEST03\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\India\INDIPLMTEST03\" /-y
copy "\\INDIPLMTEST04\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\India\INDIPLMTEST04\" /-y
copy "\\ind005558\PerfLogs\Logs\" "C:\Test_Results\India\IND005558\" /-y
Exit
```

Tualatin-script.bat is placed on the remote server:
I/P: It will automatically pick the files from another remote server when invoked from my local
Expected output:- I need to know it runs with an error or successfully, Error may be no access or files don't exist.

Comment: You should be using `Call Script\India-script.bat`, `Call Script\Tualatin-script.bat` and `Call Script\villach-script.bat`, not `Start /B Script\India-script.bat`, `Start /B Script\Tualatin-script.bat` and `Start /B Script\villach-script.bat`.

Comment: I did that also, it works on local but on the remote machine.

Comment: I wasn't providing you with an answer to your question, _(that would have gone in the answer section)_, I was commenting, _(in the comment area)_, that `Call` is the proper way to do it, not `Start`. **Your question is unclear, you don't tell us which `.bat` you're wanting to trigger, or indeed which `.bat` files you've posted, their relevance to your problem, or what commands you're expecting success or error messages returned from.**

Comment: create one hello.bat on remote system try running it through ur system, I need confirmation that it executed successfully.

Comment: I have no need or desire to do that! You need to fully explain your situation, providing relevant example code and an explanation of the results you're expecting but aren't getting. Unless you do so, your question will remain unclear and you're unlikely to receive the help you require.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question, please review it and if in case you don't find all relevant info=rmation please let me know, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I would like to have relevant logs of it.